# How to catch "Python Not Responding" exception?

Tags: python

I used this function below to keep the Python program pressing 'enter" over and over again, but when I click with the mouse, a window appears with "Python Not Responding" and then I have to close the program, so my question is; is there any way for me to catch that with Python?

Code:

```
def stop():
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
    while True:
        pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't catch it because it's not an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `catch` your program crashing as if it were an exception. What you can do in add a delay between sending each key press:

```
import time
def stop():
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
    while True:
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Thank u for the reply, but this did not solve the issue.